# Auto-populate _link-ed member objects when consuming HAL based APIs with RestTemplate

Tags: json, spring, resttemplate, hateoas

Using Spring RestTemplate, I'd like to consume a HAL based REST service with a simplified configuration like this:

`GET http://my.rest.service/items/123` returns

```
{
    "_links": {
        "category": {
            "href": "/categories/321"
        },
        "self": {
            "href": "/items/123"
        }
    },
    "name": "my wonderful item"
}
```

A GET on `http://my.rest.service/categories/321` will then accordingly return the category my item is assigned to (which looks quite similar to the JSON above).

What I can do up to now (and what is working :)) is some "manual" link-following:

```java
public Item getItemById(Integer itemId) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplateWithHalMessageConverter();

    ResponseEntity<Resource<Budget>> response =
        restTemplate.exchange("http://my.rest.service/items/"+itemId,
            HttpMethod.GET, getHttpEntity(), 
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resource<Item>>() {}
        );

    ResponseEntity<Resource<Category>> catResponse =
        restTemplate.exchange("http://my.rest.service/" + 
            response.getBody().getLink("category").getHref(),
            HttpMethod.GET, getHttpEntity(), 
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<Resource<Category>>() {}
        );

    Item result = response.getBody().getContent();
    //^^ Now this is an item with NULL in category field

    result.setCategory(catResponse.getBody().getContent());
    //And voila, now the category is assigned

    return result;
}
```

(I didn't post the "helper" functions like `getRestTemplateWithHalMessageConverter()` here as IMHO they are not relevant for this question, especially as they work as expected.)

What I would like to achieve is "auto-following" the links in the HAL response and populate my Java objects respectively.

So, my question is, is there any way to get "automatic" `_link` following, such that my `Item` will be fully populated without the second `exchange` etc.? This is a simple example, but I have more complex objects with many links. Of course, one can assume, that the matching fields exist in the particular classes.

And on bonus question ;) : Can this be used alongside with some kind of caching? If I have 30 items with category `8`, I wouldn't like having 30 calls to the `category` endpoint...

If there is no out-of-the-box solution for both questions (at least I didn't find one...) and I'll have to write my own, I'm fine with that! Just want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel just because I missed something...

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bowman](https://github.com/BlackPepperSoftware/bowman) to consume JSON+HAL resources in JAVA. This library greatly simplifies the consumption of resources comparing to RestTemplate as shown in [this article](https://hdpe.me/post/spring-data-rest-hal-client/).

This library answers the "automatic link following" part :

> Our client is a wrapper around Spring HATEOAS and Jackson with a heavy
>   JPA influence. Retrieving an object from the remote returns a proxy of
>   the returned object, instrumented using Javassist, whose accessors can
>   transparently conduct further remote service invocations in accordance
>   with its HAL links. This allows linked and inline associations to both
>   be defined in the same way in the client model and greatly simplifies
>   client code.

Comment: Indeed it looks as if Bowman fits for my purpose. Anyway, in the meantime I have implemented my own solution that matches 100%. Quite sure it's not as sophisticated or versatile as bowman, but I'm going to publish it on GitHub anyway as perhaps it's helpful though. :) I'll add another answer when this happened.

Answer (score 0):

After a while a have finished implementing my own solution to my original question (beginning before I was kindly pointed towards Bowman by baxbong).

In case there is anyone else with quite the same needs as I had, you can find my implementation here:

https://github.com/ahuemmer/storesthal

As described there, I will go on and extend it as there is some demand (by me or by others). :) Everyone is, of course, free to open issues or pull requests!